# PL/SQL Procedure not returns any

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to do a stored procedure in SQL Developer, which returns multiple records from a single table. But when I call the procedure, it returns the empty variables (taking into account that the table has records).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PURE_ENC_SELECCIONAR_INTERACCIONES(
   startDate IN varchar2, 
   endDate IN varchar2,
   o_interactionId OUT PURE_ENC_INTERACTION.INTERACTIONID%TYPE,
   o_interactionDate OUT PURE_ENC_INTERACTION.INTERACTIONDATE%TYPE,
   o_queueId OUT PURE_ENC_INTERACTION.QUEUEID%TYPE,
   o_personId OUT PURE_ENC_INTERACTION.PERSONID%TYPE,
   o_numSolicitud OUT PURE_ENC_INTERACTION.NUMSOLICITUD%TYPE,
   o_customerDni OUT PURE_ENC_INTERACTION.CUSTOMERDNI%TYPE,
   o_customerName OUT PURE_ENC_INTERACTION.CUSTOMERNAME%TYPE,
   o_ani OUT PURE_ENC_INTERACTION.ANI%TYPE,
   o_dnis OUT PURE_ENC_INTERACTION.DNIS%TYPE, 
   o_custom1 OUT PURE_ENC_INTERACTION.CUSTOM1%TYPE,
   o_custom2 OUT PURE_ENC_INTERACTION.CUSTOM2%TYPE, 
   o_custom3 OUT PURE_ENC_INTERACTION.CUSTOM3%TYPE,
   o_custom4 OUT PURE_ENC_INTERACTION.CUSTOM4%TYPE,
   o_custom5 OUT PURE_ENC_INTERACTION.CUSTOM5%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN 
 FOR loop_int IN (
   SELECT INTERACTIONID, INTERACTIONDATE, QUEUEID, PERSONID, NUMSOLICITUD, CUSTOMERDNI,
          CUSTOMERNAME, ANI, DNIS, CUSTOM1, CUSTOM2, CUSTOM3, CUSTOM4, CUSTOM5
   INTO o_interactionId, o_interactionDate, o_queueId, o_personId, o_numSolicitud, 
          o_customerDni, o_customerName, o_ani, o_dnis, o_custom1, o_custom2, o_custom3, 
          o_custom4, o_custom5
   FROM PURE_ENC_INTERACTION )
        --WHERE INTERACTIONDATE >= startDate AND INTERACTIONDATE < endDate )
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('InteractionID: '|| o_interactionId);
   END LOOP loop_int;
END;
```

I execute the procedure:

```
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE 
   o_interactionId VARCHAR2(200);
   o_interactionDate VARCHAR2(200);
   o_queueId VARCHAR2(200);
   o_personId VARCHAR2(200);
   o_numSolicitud VARCHAR2(200);
   o_customerDni VARCHAR2(200);
   o_customerName VARCHAR2(200);
   o_ani VARCHAR2(200);
   o_dnis VARCHAR2(200);
   o_custom1 VARCHAR2(200);
   o_custom2 VARCHAR2(200);
   o_custom3 VARCHAR2(200);
   o_custom4 VARCHAR2(200);
   o_custom5 VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  PURE_ENC_SELECCIONAR_INTERACCIONES(
     '2019-10-20T12:30:03',
     '2019-10-29T03:30:03',
     o_interactionId,
     o_interactionDate,
     o_queueId,
     o_personId,
     o_numSolicitud,
     o_customerDni,
     o_customerName,
     o_ani,
     o_dnis,
     o_custom1,
     o_custom2,
     o_custom3,
     o_custom4,
     o_custom5);
END;
```

When I run it, returns:

```
Procedimiento PL/SQL terminado correctamente.
InteractionID: 
InteractionID: 
InteractionID: 
InteractionID: 
InteractionID: 
InteractionID: 
InteractionID: 
InteractionID: 
InteractionID: 
InteractionID: 
InteractionID: 
InteractionID: 
InteractionID: 
InteractionID: 
InteractionID: 
InteractionID:
```

When I run this sample:

```
SELECT INTERACTIONID, INTERACTIONDATE, QUEUEID , PERSONID , NUMSOLICITUD , CUSTOMERDNI , CUSTOMERNAME , ANI , DNIS , CUSTOM1,CUSTOM2 ,CUSTOM3 ,CUSTOM4 ,CUSTOM5  
FROM PURE_ENC_INTERACTION;
```

It returns all the registers fine.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't post what you exactly have. How do I know? Because the procedure has syntax errors. You can't use cursor `FOR` loop like that; `INTO` is required for `SELECT` statements in PL/SQL, but not where you used it.

Simplified, on Scott's schema, this is what you did:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_deptno in number, par_ename out varchar2) is
  2  begin
  3    for cur_r in (select ename from emp into par_ename
  4                  where deptno = par_deptno)
  5    loop
  6      dbms_output.put_line('Ename: ' || par_ename);
  7    end loop;
  8  end;
  9  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE P_TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/17     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
3/39     PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
SQL>
```

As I said: your code is invalid.

---

This, on the other hand, is valid:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_deptno in number, par_ename out varchar2) is
  2  begin
  3    for cur_r in (select ename from emp
  4                  where deptno = par_deptno)
  5    loop
  6      par_ename := cur_r.ename;
  7      dbms_output.put_line('Ename from P_TEST: ' || par_ename);
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL> declare
  2    l_ename varchar2(20);
  3  begin
  4    p_test (10, l_ename);
  5    dbms_output.put_line('Ename from anonymous PL/SQL block: ' || l_ename);
  6  end;
  7  /
Ename from P_TEST: CLARK
Ename from P_TEST: KING
Ename from P_TEST: MILLER
Ename from anonymous PL/SQL block: MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

But, it is **wrong** (logically). The procedure fetched all employees (Clark, King, Miller), but the caller (i.e. the anonymous PL/SQL block) got only one value: the last one fetched by the cursor.

I doubt that this is what you want; doesn't make sense.

I don't know what you really want; perhaps it is to return all rows that satisfy certain condition. If that's the case, you can't return scalar values, that should be *something

```
else*. Ref cursor is one option, but - you don't need a procedure with bunch of parameters, then - maybe a function is a better option. For example:

SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_deptno in number)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open l_rc for select ename from emp where deptno = par_deptno;
  7    return l_rc;
  8  end;
  9  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test(10) from dual;

F_TEST(10)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

ENAME
----------
CLARK
KING
MILLER


SQL>
```